# Connecting through usb-serial driver

Tags: usb, serial, java

I am trying to communicate with a machine connected to a usb port using the cp210x driver of the RPi. I have a java method which open a FileOutputStream and a FileInputStream for each /dev/ttyUSBX file. It then demands the machine to return an ID and if this ID is correct, the connection is set.

This is not working properly so far, except if I install a small software. 
This small software asks me to **"register"** the device I'm trying to connect. Once I've done this step, the communication is set properly. If I uninstall this software, or un-register the device, it is not working anymore.

My problem is that I have no idea what this little software does and how I can communicate without. So here's my question :

1. Is there a way to know what exactly a software do while running ?
2. How do I "register" a usb device on RPi (if that's something common) ?
3. Is there a better way to set up the usb-serial connection (through java code, if possible, sorry if that's not the right place to ask) ?

Through "lsusb" command, I know that the device uses the cp210x driver, but I'm still new to linux environment and don't fully understand how drivers and ports work.

[EDIT]

I've managed to make the serial usb work : I just tried to spy on the port when communicating with it, through the command **stty raw -echo < /dev/ttyUSB0; cat -vte /dev/ttyUSB0**. Now I need to now exactly what this does on the port (some kind of "clear" or "dump" I guess), and do it before accessing this port.

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: for the first question: you can use `strace -p <PID>`  to trace the system calls of the software

Comment: This question is really unclear. **some** software is used to register **some** device which then communicates via UART using **some** sort of protocol. Even if I had exactly the same problem as you, there would be no way for me realize that I could use the answer, not to mention finding your question in the first place.

Comment: I realize that my question lacks of information, and that is actually my whole problem : this software is not accessible to public and I don't have much intel on it, same thing for the device. I hesitated a long time before posting it, for I knew there was not much you could help me with, with so little info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice. I manage to make it work by changing the ttyUSB settings with the ***stty*** command. By removing some special character (with *-canon* and *-isig*), my program can now communicate with my device, without using the third-part software.

So if one day you are having trouble with a device you don't know much about, but the driver cp210x seems to work, you can try that.